# Fix gap between related windows?

Tags: windows, windows-10

After installing TeamViewer I noticed a gap between the two windows it launches. Does anyone know if a fix?

[image]

Comment: pix or didn't happen.

Comment: aren't you able to move the window to the right to minimize the gap, or is the problem with starting position? Windows is does not have a tiling window manager.

Comment: Unable to move the window over only way, it locks in that position if you "snap" them together.